# Transpose rows to column after nth column in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

I have a file like below format:

```
$ cat file_in.csv

1308123;28/01/2019;28/01/2019;22/01/2019
1308456;20/11/2018;27/11/2018;09/11/2018;15/11/2018;10/11/2018;02/12/2018
1308789;06/12/2018;04/12/2018  
1308012;unknown
```

How can i transpose as below, starting from second column:

```
1308123;28/01/2019  
1308123;28/01/2019  
1308123;22/01/2019  
1308456;20/11/2018  
1308456;27/11/2018  
1308456;09/11/2018  
1308456;15/11/2018  
1308456;10/11/2018  
1308456;02/12/2018  
1308789;06/12/2018  
1308789;04/12/2018  
1308012;unknown
```

I'm testing my script, but obtain a wrong result

```
echo "123;23/05/2018;24/05/2018" | awk -F";" 'NR==3{a=$1";";next}{a=a$1";"}END{print a}'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Eaisest solution will be, loop through all fields(off course have set field separator as `;`) and then print `$1` along with all fields in new line. Also note that loop is running from `i=2` to till value of `NF` leaving first field since we need to print in new line from column 2nd onwards.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i}}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd Solution:*** Using 1 time substitution(`sub`) and global substitutions(`gsub`) functionality of `awk`. Here I am changing very first occurence of `;` with `@@@`(assumed that your Input_file will NOT have this characters together, in case it is there choose any unique character(s) which are NOT in one's Input_file on place of `@@@`), then globally subsituting `;`(all occurences) with `ORS` val(a variable which has value of $1) and `;` so make values in new column. Now finally remove `@@@` from first field. Why we have done this approch if we DO NOT substitute very first occurence of `;` with any other character then it will place a NEW LINE before substituion which we DO NOT want to have. (Also as per Ed sir's comment this solution was tested in 1 Input_file and may have issues while reading multiple Input_files)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {val=$1;sub(";","@@@");gsub(";",ORS val ";");sub("@@@",";",$1)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: That 2nd solution can fail given so many input values, I personally would never do it. The first solution is fine though.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir for letting me know, let me add a fair warning that 2nd solution could be helpful in 1 time reading Input_file, may have issues in multiple Input_files.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk -F";" '{ OFS="\n" $1 ";"; $1=$1;$1=""; printf("%s",$0) } ' file
```